# Clickhouse: How to get averages of 2 consecutive rows?

Tags: rows, clickhouse

CREATE TABLE sensor_2 (
when DateTime64,
value Float32
) ENGINE=MergeTree
PARTITION BY toYYYYMM(when)
ORDER BY (when)

INSERT INTO sensor_2 Values
('2021-01-01 00:00:00.000', 1.52), ('2021-01-01 00:00:00.001', 1.54), ('2021-01-01 00:00:00.002', 1.42), ('2021-01-01 00:00:00.003', 1.54), ('2021-01-01 00:00:00.004', 1.42), ('2021-01-01 00:00:00.005', 1.52);

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

`when` is  always '2021-01-01 00:00:00' which rows are consecutive ?

I changed time.

```sql
CREATE TABLE sensor_2 ( when DateTime64, value Float32 ) ENGINE=MergeTree PARTITION BY toYYYYMM(when) ORDER BY (when);

INSERT INTO sensor_2 Values ('2021-01-01 00:00:00', 1.52), ('2021-01-01 00:00:01', 1.54), ('2021-01-01 00:00:02', 1.42), ('2021-01-01 00:00:03', 1.54), ('2021-01-01 00:00:04', 1.42), ('2021-01-01 00:00:05', 1.52);

SELECT
    *,
    avg(value) OVER (ORDER BY when ASC Rows BETWEEN 1 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) AS sliding_avg2
FROM sensor_2
┌────────────────────when─┬─value─┬───────sliding_avg2─┐
│ 2021-01-01 00:00:00.000 │  1.52 │ 1.5199999809265137 │
│ 2021-01-01 00:00:01.000 │  1.54 │ 1.5299999713897705 │
│ 2021-01-01 00:00:02.000 │  1.42 │ 1.4799999594688416 │
│ 2021-01-01 00:00:03.000 │  1.54 │ 1.4799999594688416 │
│ 2021-01-01 00:00:04.000 │  1.42 │ 1.4799999594688416 │
│ 2021-01-01 00:00:05.000 │  1.52 │ 1.4699999690055847 │
└─────────────────────────┴───────┴────────────────────┘

SELECT
    when,
    value,
    (value + neighbor(value, -1)) / 2 AS sliding_avg2
FROM
(
    SELECT *
    FROM sensor_2
    ORDER BY when ASC
)

┌────────────────────when─┬─value─┬───────sliding_avg2─┐
│ 2021-01-01 00:00:00.000 │  1.52 │ 0.7599999904632568 │
│ 2021-01-01 00:00:01.000 │  1.54 │ 1.5299999713897705 │
│ 2021-01-01 00:00:02.000 │  1.42 │ 1.4799999594688416 │
│ 2021-01-01 00:00:03.000 │  1.54 │ 1.4799999594688416 │
│ 2021-01-01 00:00:04.000 │  1.42 │ 1.4799999594688416 │
│ 2021-01-01 00:00:05.000 │  1.52 │ 1.4699999690055847 │
└─────────────────────────┴───────┴────────────────────┘
```

Comment: Yes, the time is basically the same. The sensor output is 1KHz so there are a thousand points for each second. I need to GROUP the data BY (i) 4 consecutive rows (ii) 24 consecutive rows (iii) 1440 consecutive rows. How can I GROUP BY N consecutive rows?

Comment: Just use my examples?

Comment: Where specify the number of consecutive rows?

Comment: The example you gave me is not solving my challenge. I want to GROUP the data by N consecutive rows, then calculate its averages. If N = 2 then from 6 rows the final table should have 3 rows. i.e. 6/N

Comment: Your example is not helping. I understood pretty nothing. Provide normal input and desired output.